# How does Google detect which version of google.com to serve based on my location or browser language?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization

I am trying to detect the users prefered language in ASP.NET MVC and I am aware of the `Request.UserLanguages` property. The thing is, it seems that the most popular sites on the internet for instance Google.com do not use these settings but rather use some location based settings. That's why by default I always see the Slovenian version of Google.com even if we removed all the traces of Slovenian language from Languages in our browsers (be it IE, Chrome, etc.)

Going abroad and connecting to the networks there will also result in showing, for instance, German Google.com when traveling to Germany.

My questions are:

1. What detection mechanism they use?
2. Do you favor UserLanguages or would you favor location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What detection mechanism they use?

IP based.

> Do you favor UserLanguages or would you favor location?

Depends on your requirements. As you've already noticed if you use UserLanguages, you could have an user in China having configured his browser for en-EU and you get English whereas if you use IP based detection you will get China. So it will really depend whether you want to privilege user location or user browser settings.

Comment: Could you provide more details on IP based language/culture detection (maybe a service I could use)?

Comment: Proxies can/will ruin IP based detection.

Comment: @TheZ, got better idea? Google doesn't. So for example if you are in France using an US proxy you get the US version of Google.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I don't necessarily have a better idea (except maybe: don't try) but pointing out the flaws exposes potential pitfalls from _relying_ on the technique to be 100% accurate.

Comment: @TheZ, hopefully all people calling themselves *web developers* already know that there is no 100% bulletproof technique fro detecting where the client of a web site comes from so I really thought this was so obvious that it wasn't necessary mentioning it.

Comment: Ok, I guess if we take an average user he will have his OS setup by someone else most likely in the store or enterprise wide. That same average user most likely wouldn't want to change his Language settings or wouldn't know how, so if most likely he is using his native tongue to use computer then I guess UserLanguages should win. I would guess there are a lot more users that travel and still want their sites in the same language than those that either travel or not but do change their Language settings. Does that make sense?

Comment: @mare, don't guess. I mean you have to define what and how your web site must behave, shouldn't you? Haven't you written some specifications? How do you want your web site to behave in those situations? Anyway it is clear that you have 2 possibilities: browser language settings and IP detection. So go figure. Talk to your clients, write specifications, ...

Comment: @DarinDimitrov You just made the "100%" mistake, you _assumed_ that a web dev would know. See that it can/does/will happen?

Comment: @TheZ, that's not an assumption. For me someone who doesn't know this is **not** a web developer. He is probably learning to become some day a web developer. That's why I said that a web developer already must know this.

Comment: My specs are simple: render Slovenian to all users with Slovenian in UserLanguages (in the top position) and to all others render English. Now the only thing is, I am wondering if I should introduce IP based detection into the picture.

Comment: @mare, in this case browser language detection should be enough. Whether you should introduce IP based detection is not a question you should ask here. It's a question you should discuss with your team, users, managers, ... I hope you get the point.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov with regards to your webdev comments, I actually did make quite a few multilingual sites before but didn't run into a dilemma of whether to use location or not for language selection before. So I wouldn't make such categorical assumptions when a certain person is or isn't web developer given that many of us actually work as pros on web development but there might be certain scenarios where we might lack some knowledge.

Comment: @mare, you misunderstood me. I said that for me someone cannot call himself a web developer if he doesn't know IP based detection is not 100% reliable because this IP could be the one of a proxy server. I never said that for me someone who doesn't know whether he should use user language or IP based detection is not a web developer. Please don't get me wrong. Anyway, I get the feeling that we are getting waaaaaay off-topic here. Do you have some other specific questions (the one whether you should introduce or not IP based detection on your website is not something suitable for SO question)?

Comment: ok;) and thanks..of course I understand neither of these options is 100% certain...FWIW you could have an English user that sits down behind a China based computer and most likely he will get everything rendered for China and there is no way one could detect that, of course.

Comment: @mare, lol, yeah, the same way you have no way of detecting whether the user loves beer (as in my case) and offer him a free one on your site. It's a pity they haven't thought about this in the [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) :-)

Comment: However, it could be that Google.com (since it's a search engine specifically) decides to use IP geolocation because even for an Italian person in Germany it is very likely that this person will search on Google while in Germany for german results, that is, german companies, hotels in Germany, etc..that could be the motivation behind this Google's decision..

Comment: I am moving this to chat if anyone else decides to comment on it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15295/discussion-between-mare-and-darin-dimitrov)